# Meaning of knots when drawing a NURBS curve?

Tags: opengl, 3d, graphics

I'm using `gluNurbsCurve` to draw some curves with some control points. I've got the basic setup as described in the red book working correctly and I'm trying to expand on it.
This sample looks like this:

```
float knots[8] = {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1};
float pnts[4][3] = { {...},{...},{...},{...} };
GLUnurbsObj *m = gluNewNurbsRenderer();
gluBeginCurve(n);
gluNurbsCurve(n, 8, knots, 3, pnts, 4, GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3)
gluEndCurve(n);
```

One thing I was wondering about is the meaning of the knots data. How does it affect the result? What other options can I experiment there?
For some reason I could not find any tutorial which properly explains this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.rhino3d.com/nurbs.htm) page has good explanations.

> The knots are a list of degree+N-1 numbers, where N is the number of
>   control points. Sometimes this list of
>   numbers is called the knot vector. In
>   this term, the word vector does not
>   mean 3‑D direction.
>
> This list of knot numbers must satisfy
>   several technical conditions. The
>   standard way to ensure that the
>   technical conditions are satisfied is
>   to require the numbers to stay the
>   same or get larger as you go down the
>   list and to limit the number of
>   duplicate values to no more than the
>   degree. For example, for a degree 3
>   NURBS curve with 11 control points,
>   the list of numbers
>   0,0,0,1,2,2,2,3,7,7,9,9,9 is a
>   satisfactory list of knots. The list
>   0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,7,7,9,9,9 is
>   unacceptable because there are four 2s
>   and four is larger than the degree.
>
> The number of times a knot value is
>   duplicated is called the knot’s
>   multiplicity. In the preceding example
>   of a satisfactory list of knots, the
>   knot value 0 has multiplicity three,
>   the knot value 1 has multiplicity one,
>   the knot value 2 has multiplicity
>   three, the knot value 3 has
>   multiplicity one, the knot value 7 has
>   multiplicity two, and the knot value 9
>   has multiplicity three. A knot value
>   is said to be a full-multiplicity knot
>   if it is duplicated degree many times.
>   In the example, the knot values 0, 2,
>   and 9 have full multiplicity. A knot
>   value that appears only once is called
>   a simple knot. In the example, the
>   knot values 1 and 3 are simple knots.
>
> If a list of knots starts with a full
>   multiplicity knot, is followed by
>   simple knots, terminates with a full
>   multiplicity knot, and the values are
>   equally spaced, then the knots are
>   called uniform. For example, if a
>   degree 3 NURBS curve with 7 control
>   points has knots 0,0,0,1,2,3,4,4,4,
>   then the curve has uniform knots. The
>   knots 0,0,0,1,2,5,6,6,6 are not
>   uniform. Knots that are not uniform
>   are called non‑uniform. The N and U in
>   NURBS stand for non‑uniform and
>   indicate that the knots in a NURBS
>   curve are permitted to be non-uniform.
>
> Duplicate knot values in the middle of
>   the knot list make a NURBS curve less
>   smooth. At the extreme, a full
>   multiplicity knot in the middle of the
>   knot list means there is a place on
>   the NURBS curve that can be bent into
>   a sharp kink. For this reason, some
>   designers like to add and remove knots
>   and then adjust control points to make
>   curves have smoother or kinkier
>   shapes. Since the number of knots is
>   equal to (N+degree‑1), where N is the
>   number of control points, adding knots
>   also adds control points and removing
>   knots removes control points. Knots
>   can be added without changing the
>   shape of a NURBS curve. In general,
>   removing knots will change the shape
>   of a curve.